# How to get object value only without mentioning key from array list using ngFor in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have an array list which has list of emp objects. I want to iterate in html using *ngFor loop. But I do not want to give like `{{emp.empname}}`. I want to get values only with out mentioning the key with emp object.

```
const epmloyees = [
                    {'empname': 'kumaresan', 'id': 2}, 
                    {'empname': 'perumal', 'id': 3},
                  ]
```

HTML code

```
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of epmloyees ">

        <td scope="row" class="font-weight-bold">{{emp}}</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe for Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs..

```
<div *ngFor="let e of epmloyees">
  <div *ngFor="let p of e | keyvalue:desc">
    {{p.key}}{{p.value}}    //You can get here `key` and `value`
   </div>
</div>


desc = (a, b) => {
   if(a.key < b.key) return b.key;
}
```

Comment: Hi here is stackblitz link its work well https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crmk3d

Comment: for sorting order you can use `desc` filter

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let emp of Object.values(epmloyees)">
 <td scope="row" class="font-weight-bold">{{emp}}</td>
```